# how import data from csv to PostgreSQL automatically everyday

Tags: postgresql, csv

I receive a daily csv file of measurements for each location, i want to connect the csv files with my postgresql database for automatic updating, and i also want to make queries to view the history.

automate csv import to postgresql

Comment: You can save the [`copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) you normally do this with as a `psql -c` command in a [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [`schtasks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks) job.

Comment: If the table is supposed to mirror the file rather than accumulate daily batches, you can also use [`file_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) and link it up to be accessible as a table directly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.